# Emacs configuration for dirtree

Tags: emacs

I'm currently trying to get dirtree for Emacs working. I'm unfamiliar with configuration files and I'm having trouble getting it to work. Currently I have dirtree.el, along with the other required files, inside of my `.emacs.d` directory, and I've added the following lines to my `.emacs` file.

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/")
(autoload 'dirtree "dirtree" "Add directory to tree view")
```

I don't get any errors when I open Emacs, but when I type `M-x dirtree`, I get a message saying there is no match.  Can anyone see what I'm missing in order to get this to work correctly?

The dirtree that I'm using can be found at: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/dirtree.el

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is in the `autoload` declaration suggested by the library. It does not include the `interactive` flag to tell Emacs that it is a command (interactive function), and only commands may be invoked via <kbd>M-x</kbd>.

The corrected declaration is:

```
(autoload 'dirtree "dirtree" "Add directory to tree view" t)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to load it on my machine. It seems that `dirtree` requires a second module called `tree-mode` (which I don't have installed). Did you install that one too? If not, you may have the same error.

By the way, you shouldn't have to add `~/.emacs.d` to your load path; I'm reasonably sure it's there by default.

Comment: I thought that ~/.emacs.d was already in the load path, but examples that I tried from online had it, so I put it there...  I have tree-mode as well as windata in the same directory as I have dirtree.